# Shell panel with help of Tikz!

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just want to know if it’s possible to draw something like this in `TikZ`? Is there a template to use? Its the first time I decided to use this, I know it is really powerful, but I didn't see anything like this in `TikZ`.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Yes. No. See the "Minimal Introduction" at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . It's not difficult, but as a beginner in Latex and Tikz it may take a while. // Please feel free to add your code-attempts to your question via the EDIT button, later. // You may also want to visit a tikz gallery, like https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/arcs/ or https://texample.net/tikz/examples/area/optics/ .

Comment: See also these images: https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-9dfa5d59bec941f2154e71954ed4b03b-pjlq and https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0da6e87a220c0db9c616a6a1628622f8-pjlq from https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-draw-professional-physics-diagrams-in-LaTeX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to start with:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    % shape
    \draw 
        % front
        (0:0) -- (40:5) arc[start angle=40, end angle=110, radius=5] -- cycle
        % top
        (40:5) -- ++(1,2) coordinate (AA) 
        arc[start angle=40, end angle=110, radius=5] coordinate (AB) -- ++(-1,-2) 
        arc[start angle=110, end angle=40, radius=5] -- cycle;
    \draw[dashed]
        % lower layer
        (40:4.5) -- ++(1,2) coordinate (BA) 
        arc[start angle=40, end angle=110, radius=4.5] coordinate (BB) -- ++(-1,-2)
        (AA) -- (BA)
        (AB) -- (BB);
    \draw 
        % lower layer front
        (40:4.5) arc[start angle=40, end angle=110, radius=4.5];
    \draw[dotted]
        % middle layer
        (40:4.75) -- ++(1,2) coordinate (CA) 
        arc[start angle=40, end angle=110, radius=4.75] coordinate (CB) -- ++(-1,-2);
    \draw[dash dot]
        % middle layer front
        (40:4.75) arc[start angle=40, end angle=110, radius=4.75] node[midway, left] {$S$};

    % labels
    \draw (75:0) -- (75:4.75) node[midway, right] {$R$};

    \draw[<->] (110:0.5) arc[start angle=110, end angle=40, radius=0.5] 
        node[pos=0.25, above] {$\theta$};

    \draw (110:0) (110:5) [turn] -- (0,10pt) coordinate (DA);
    \draw (110:0) (110:4.5) [turn] -- (0,10pt) coordinate (DB);
    \draw[->] ($(DA)!-0.5!(DB)$) -- (DA);
    \draw[->] ($(DB)!-0.5!(DA)$) -- (DB);
    \node at ($(DA)!0.5!(DB)$) {$h$};

    \draw (110:0) (40:5) [turn] -- (0,-10pt) coordinate (EA);
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1,2)}]
        \draw (110:0) (40:5) [turn] -- (0,-10pt) coordinate (EB);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[<->] (EA) -- (EB) node[midway, right] {$L$};

    \draw (110:4.75) -- ++(0,2) coordinate (FA);
    \draw (40:4.75) -- ++(0,2) coordinate (FB);
    \draw[<->] (FA) -- (FB) node[midway, above] {$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !!